# Generating a Variable Based on Criteria in Another Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, subset, stata

I have two dataframes in my current project: one contains survey data on household size (number of adults over 18) and income, and the other contains federal poverty guidelines (FPG) by household size for 2018. For instance, the FPG stipulate that a household with one adult is living in poverty if their annual income is less than or equal to $12,140.

I want to create a dummy variable in the first dataframe that identifies whether a household, based on size and income, is considered in poverty. I know how I would go about this in R (df1 being the first dataframe I mentioned, df2 the second):

```
for row in c(1:nrow(df1)) {
  if (household size[row] == 1) {
  ifelse (df1$income[row] <= df2[1,2], 1,0)
  }
}
```

where `df2[1,2]` references the cell containing the poverty threshold for a family of size one, and so on for each household size. However, I'm not sure how to achieve this in Stata. I'm new to the language, and it seems much more difficult to work with multiple dataframes in the same environment at the same time.

Comment: Please give a data example from Stata.

Comment: I have the data referenced in the post loaded in Stata, I'm just not sure how to achieve the Stata equivalent of the R code I posted.

Comment: I don't doubt that you understand your own question (no sarcasm there). Even if your problem is really about translating from R to Stata, you're hoping for people fluent in both to answer that. But the number of people fluent in Stata is necessary more than the number fluent in Stata and R, so you're better off giving an example of your data in Stata and stating what you want. Otherwise in Stata terms this question will seem unclear  to most people who answer Stata questions here.

Comment: Ah, I see - my apologies for misunderstanding. Let me know if this is what you’re looking for. The first df has household size and income level. If I wanted to create a dummy to identify poverty status for a household of size one, it might look something like this (I could be wrong, again, very new!): generate poverty = 0, replace poverty = 1 if household size == 1 & income < 12,140. But instead of using the number 12,140, I want to reference the cell in the other dataframe I have imported which specifies that, for a house of size one, the FPG says the poverty threshold is 12,140.

Comment: I think the issue with the question is that it does not ask the question in a Stata flavored way or in a high level way. Your question is very R flavored. Then it becomes "how do you approach a task in Stata in the way you would in R?". Well, you do not, in Stata you would approach it in a Stata way. That in this case would be merging the two datasets instead of combining specific single features.

Comment: The Stata way would be in your case to merge df1 and df2 and then do something similar to what you are suggesting in your comment.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. Like I said, very new to Stata and not quite sure yet how to approach things in a "Stata way." But I'm sure I'll get there someday!

Comment: I agree with @TheIceBear. Still true that a detailed answer is more likely if a data example and Stata code so far are given within the question. The `stata` tag wiki gives very detailed advice.

Comment: @MarkWeiss, make an attempt in Stata and if you cannot solve it, edit your question to update it with the Stata code and I am sure someone here will be happy and able to help you